# What event is fired after a customer places an order?

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer

so I've been looking to do some adjustments with an observer by listening to the event that is fired after a user **successfully** places an order, whether in the **backend** or the **frontend**. But, I don't know which event I'm looking for. My best guesses are:

1. checkout_submit_all_after
2. checkout_controller_onepage_saveOrder
   I got the above events from [This list of Magento 2 events](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/event-list.html#catalog_product_edit_action)

Can someone help me understand which event I need? and which of the ones I provided, if any,is correct and why? and what's the difference between both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sales_order_place_after

Below is the sample code of the and event which is trigered when order is placed.
**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="my_event_name" instance="Foo\Bar\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**MyObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $orderInstance Order */
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getRealOrderId();

        \Zend_Debug::dump($orderId);
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. ill use this code and if it works ill mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: yes let me know if you need any more help

Comment: I adjusted my question. I noticed that I wasn't being very clear about which event I wanted. And I was confused about only one thing in your code which is "/** \@var $orderInstance Order **/" can you tell me which class I need to import so that I can check its methods.

Comment: that code was just a sample, you can add your own logic in execute method

Answer (score 3):

`sales_order_place_after`  is fire when  `place()` of order object is called  and in **magento every payment does not call place()** when  order placed.

---

Where

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

Is **only called when customer** has  been redirect to `checout/onepage/success`. Also this event **only called whenever** **order place from frontend** and customer visit `checout/onepage/success`.

MY suggestion, this two event not proper,We should be use **`checkout_submit_all_after`** this event is fire when order place from frontend and backend.

it is fire immediate order place